# How to get last modified date of file from sd card

Tags: android, android-file

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/tjvideohighlight.techjini.com.tjvideohighlight/filesMoment_01.mp4  this is my Directory of file

```
public String getFilecreationDate(String fileName) {
        String filePath = context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + fileName;

        File file = new File(filePath);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        return sdf.format(file.lastModified());
    }
```

This is code i am using to get file modified date but each time i am getting 
**01/01/1970 08:00:00** for every file while all file i have save today can any one please tell me how to get file last modified where am doing wrong.

Comment: That's the start of time. Suppose the field modified never got set. In other words did you modify the file after it was created?

Comment: yes after rename also same date i am getting can u please tell me how to get last modified date  of file

Comment: i am not sure how is this even works for you, as far as i know `SimpleDateFormat#format()` takes a `Date` param, and `File#lastModified()` returnrs a `long` time in mill-seconds, so maybe you have to change the line like this `return sdf.format(new Date(file.lastModified()));` if this works for you i will post as answer

Comment: one more thing, you need to check that `file` reference; it could be not what you think it is, check the path of the file `filePath` you are using to create that instance of `file` could be wrong, or points to a non-exist file in a different path, try to log the path, or log the value of `file.exists()`

Comment: same i don't know why i always get   01/01/1970 08:00:00

Comment: then i think it's the path, print that value and see if it's what you think it is